# Linux Mint CPU cores balancing and high temperature

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cpu

I am using Linux Mint. My laptop has a Core i5 CPU. When I check the system monitor, it shows that the CPU 1 usage is between 90 to 100% and CPU 2,3,4 are less than 5%. Why doesn't it balance processes onto all cores? Because of high CPU 1 usage, the fan always works and the temperature is high. In Windows I had not this problem.

Comment: Please post the output of `top -bn 2 -d 0.01| head -20` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ top -bn 2 -d 0.01| head -20
top - 19:24:35 up  1:28,  3 users,  load average: 0,96, 0,94, 0,93
Tasks: 197 total,   2 running, 195 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8,0 us,  2,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 88,4 id,  0,8 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   8085060 total,  2308068 used,  5776992 free,    91992 buffers
KiB Swap:  8142844 total,        0 used,  8142844 free,  1504860 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
   79 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  71,5  0,0  13:05.30 kworker/0:1
 2260 marek     20   0 1716m  91m  28m S   6,5  1,2   5:37.09 cinnamon
    1 root      20   0 27732 3548 1488 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.67 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.57 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u:0H
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.02 migration/0
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:03.26 rcu_sched
   11 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.02 watchdog/0
   12 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.02 watchdog/1
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.47 ksoftirqd/1
```

You can see the governing mode like so:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
ondemand
```